# SPRING + JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back

Tags: spring, transactions, jta

I've trouble with spring+JTA!
I've a function annotated to `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` and this function runs good when I store a lot of data. But I got an exception when I try to iterate and modify them in cycle lunched by quartzJob.

```
JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: The transaction was set to rollback only
```